# Create a Dialog Box from a View

Tags: android, android-view, android-dialog

I have a view defined as "public class ChessBoard extends View" in this class in one of the code flows I want to popup a Dialog box and then get a result from that dialog box. 
I have tried the answer here: [How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android) but I have no Activity to pass to the constructor.

Comment: If you're building an app for chess then I am ready to contribute if you open source it on GitHub. I have experience in .Net and a little mini-max, alpha-beta pruning.

Comment: A `View` shouldn't be showing a `Dialog` on its own. The `Activity` should be handling that.

Comment: Taimur alam: I am just building a simple logging app, I will github it as soon as there is something worthwhile to github

Comment: Mike M: You are probably correct but rewriting the whole app to use an Activity is not feasible

Comment: Taimur alam: https://github.com/Chikov2/ChessLoggerCode basically it's a chess logging app but it has a fairly extensive code (no bugs found yet) to test whether the move is valid. It can possibly be reused for any chess app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your chessboard is a view there should be a getContext()-method (see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext() ). you can cast the result to an activity:

```
Activity activity = (Activity) getContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code 
///-----------------------------------------------------

 dialog_=new Dialog(this);
                 dialog_.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_submit);//this is path of xml file
                 dialog_.show();
                 Button submit_btn=dialog_.findViewById(R.id.but_submit); //button on dialog
                 Button cancel_btn = dialog_.findViewById(R.id.but_cancel);
                 final EditText edit_username=dialog_.findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
```